# Responsive way to perfectly line up a smaller image with a specific point on a "background-size:cover" large image

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a question that comes up quite frequently when I'm building sites. I've never come up with a solution but I thought maybe some smart SO contributer might be able to work it out so here goes:

Say I have a large full page background image with `background-size:cover`. I want a specific part of the image to have a hover state e.g. Say it's a large picture of a car driving on a mountain. If you hover over the car I want it to be replaced with a glowing car.

One way I could do this is to use javascript to replace the whole background image for the same image of the mountain scene but with a glowing car. But obviously this requires an additional large image download. ([As in this example](https://codepen.io/mrbjjackson/pen/BaQVpVd)).

What would be better would be for me to have another div that covers the car and just assign a new background to the inner div which is perfectly lined up to the parent image.

This is straightforward to do in an unresponsive way ([see this example](https://codepen.io/mrbjjackson/pen/MWbXJOq)) but I can't think of a  way to do it with a responsive `background-size:cover` image.

It feels like there might be a solution, possibly using object-fit or something. But nothing springs to mind. [Here's a responsive version of the pen](https://codepen.io/mrbjjackson/pen/mdOKRzR) (which doesn't work but demonstrates my desired set up).

Can anyone think of a way of acheiving this? What other techniques could work here?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain what you want to achieve you share only your problem and thoughts

Comment: @Aman In its most simple form: I have a button inside a responsive parent div. The parent div has a background image with "background-size:cover" and the button has a background image that is a portion of the parent div's background image. I want the button to perfectly line up with the parent so that the image overlay is seemless. And I want this to be responsive.

Comment: How about using an image such as png or gif that has the same width and height but transparent background?

Comment: @JSKIM Thank you. I think this is how I will have to do it. I wanted to avoid it because it means loading two large images but actually, having tested it, a png which is mostly transparency doesn't create a very large file size.